Node js Association
In sequalize query like findAll and findAndCountAll , how can i add association of other table without including the model in the model.js
This is my current code
const {
  storeProduct,
  product,
  Location: locationModel,
  Media,  productIndex
} = require("../db").models;

const query = {
      distinct: true,
      attributes: { exclude: ["deletedAt"] },
      where,
      order,
      where,
      include: [
        {
          required: true,
          model: locationModel,
          as: "location",
          where: whereStore,
        },
       
        {
          required: true,
          model: product,
          as: "productDetail",
        },
      ],
    };

    storeProduct.hasOne(productIndex, {
      foreignKey: "product_id",
      sourceKey: "product_id",
      as: "productIndex",
  });


 const storeProducts = await storeProduct.findAndCountAll(query);


Either you can get a single value only by a subquery using Sequelize.literal or use raw SQL query because Sequelize should know all models indicated in the query and their associations
